# Автоматизация добавления вложенных словарей в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Подскажите пожалуйста, как работает добавление в словари?

Например, есть пустой словарь:

```
b = {}
```

Я хочу добавить,

```
b['id']['type'] = 5
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
>     b['id']['type'] = 5
> KeyError: 'id'
> ```

Может есть какой-то другой способ записи, кроме:

```
b['id'] = {'type': 5}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

b = defaultdict(dict)
b['id']['type'] = 5

print(b)  # defaultdict(dict, {'id': {'type': 5}})
```

Тут вы указываете, что создаете словарь, каждое значение которого по-умолчанию - пустой словарь.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 4):

Для создания новых значений с глубокой степенью вложенности можно воспользоваться модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/):

```
import dpath  #  pip install dpath

b = {}

dpath.util.new(b, '/id/type', 5)
```

результат:

```
In [79]: b
Out[79]: {'id': {'type': 5}}
```

добавляем еще один вложенный словарь:

```
dpath.util.new(b, '/id/sub1/sub2/sub3/val', [1,2,3])
```

результат:

```
In [81]: b
Out[81]: {'id': {'type': 5, 'sub1': {'sub2': {'sub3': {'val': [1, 2, 3]}}}}}
```

Comment: удобно, буду иметь ввиду, спасибо.

Comment: @Yaroslav, пожалуйста :)